# How to get exact position with imagettfbbox?

Tags: php

I want to create an image that has the exact dimensions of a given text and place that text onto that image. The position values I'm getting from imagettfbbox do not seem to be exact, especially for italic font styles. This leads to some characters being cut at the right.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

Header("Content-type: image/png");

$font = 'fonts/ArialItalic.ttf';
$text = "SOB";
$size = 48;

$bounds = imagettfbbox($size, 0, $font, $text);

$width = abs($bounds[4]-$bounds[6]);
$height = abs($bounds[7]-$bounds[1]);

$offset_y = $height;
$offset_x = $bounds[0];

$image = imagecreate($width,$height);

$background = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$foreground = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

ImageTTFText($image, $size, 0, $offset_x, $offset_y, -$foreground, $font, $text);

imagePNG($image);
imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

What I get from this is [image: Cutted edges]

What I want is: [image: Text fitting inside the image]

The calculated width and height seem to be correct; however, the X/Y positions ($offset_x and $offset_y) are not.

How can I set $offset_x and $offset_y dynamically so the text fits exactly in the image for different fonts, sizes and styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.
This is a long time PHP bug. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52756
and is still present in PHP 7.0.1

A test script for the bug can be found here: http://stuff.mindplay.dk/temp/metrics/test.php

To get my stuff working, I used an idea from a comment on php.net
http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagettfbbox.php#97357

The idea is to draw the text onto a much larger canvas and itterate over each pixel to find the exact positions from each side (top, right, bottom, left). This is pretty slow, especially on larger images but it works for me.

If anyone has another idea which is faster or more elegant I'm very interested to read it.

Comment: Just for the record. This issue is fixed in the latest PHP versions, both 5.6.29 and PHP 7.1.0 and the workaround might not be necessary any more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [library](https://github.com/unlocomqx/text-measure) on github to help you fit your text exactly

Sample code

```
$text_measure = new TextMeasure($text, $font_path, $size);
$measure = $text_measure->measureText();
```

Use the measure array like this:

```
$gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor($measure['width'], $measure['height']);
imagettftext($gd_image, $size, 0, $measure['x'], $measure['y'], $red, $font_path, $text);
```

Preview:
[image]